Get Position of clicked pixel on an image in justpy
In justpy, I would like to load an image and record which pixel a clicked on. So I need the position of the pixel of an image with an offset, not position of the mouse on screen.
JustPy click and click_out event do not give any coordinates at all, even in debug mode.
{'event_type': 'click__out', 'id': 2, 'class_name': 'Img', 'html_tag': 'img', 'vue_type': 'html_component', 'page_id': 0, 'websocket_id': 0, 'session_id': 'e0311ccc163e47df884e3cb109d046b9', 'msg_type': 'event', 'page': WebPage(page_id: 0, number of components: 2, reload interval: None), 'websocket': <starlette.websockets.WebSocket object at 0x75ae283282d0>, 'target': Img(id: 2, html_tag: img, vue_type: html_component, name: No name, number of components: 0)}

Any idea how to get the position of the pixel? Or the offset of the image on the users screen?
I read the examples on the webpage and tried different events, but failed.
import justpy as jp

def my_click1(self, msg):
self.text = 'I was clicked'
#self.log.text=msg
print(msg.event_type)
print(msg['event_type'])
print(msg)

def img_click(self, msg):
print("Image Click")
print(msg.event_type)
print(msg['event_type'])
print(msg)
print(self)

def img_clickout(self, msg):
print("Clickout")
print(msg.event_type)
print(msg['event_type'])
print(msg)
print(self)

def event_demo1():
wp = jp.WebPage()
wp.debug = True
d = jp.Div(text='Not clicked yet', a=wp, classes='w-48 text-xl m-2 p-1 bg-blue-500 text-white')
img = jp.Img(src='https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-powered-h-140x182.png', a=wp)
d.on('click', my_click1)
img.on('click', img_click)
img.on('click__out', img_clickout)
return wp

jp.justpy(event_demo1)


I would use JavaScript for this. And maybe it may need to use Canvas with image. But it seems this module hides all JavaScript and it can be the problem.

documentation shows that it can display matplotlib - so maybe you could use it to display image (it can do it) and maybe it allows you to get mouse position (in desktop programs it allows for this)

example in documentation for Handling Events - JustPy shows that you can add img.additional_properties =['screenX', 'pageY','altKey','which','movementX','button', 'buttons'] to get more values in event. It gives position of click on page but still it doesn't gives position of image.

javascript - Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element - Stack Overflow

Using img.additional_properties = ['pageX', 'pageY', 'screenX', 'screenY']
you can get mouse position on page (pageX, pageY)
To get image position I use
jp.run_task(wp.run_javascript(js_code, request_id='image_data'))

to execute JavaScript code
    js_code = f'''
    var image = document.querySelector('[name="{self.name}"]');  // put self.name
    var rect = image.getBoundingClientRect();
    //console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
    ({{image: rect, mouse:{{ pageX:{msg.pageX}, pageY:{msg.pageY}, screenX: {msg.screenX}, screenY: {msg.screenY} }} }});  // it has to be in ( )
    '''

I use f-string to put some extra values in code - so it can run with different images.
I use name from Img(.. , name=...) to find image in browser and I use getBoundingClientRect() to get its size and position.
Next I send back all information - even mouse position because it can't get it in current function but in function assigned to wp.on('result_ready', result_ready).
Because function result_ready can be used to get result from different events so I use result_id in run_javascript(..., request_id=...) to recognize this event.

Doc:

Page Events - run_javascript example

WebPage class - run_javascript



Full working code.
import justpy as jp

def result_ready(self, msg):
    #print('result_ready: self:', self)
    #print('result_ready: msg:', msg)
    #print('result_ready: msg.request_id', msg.request_id)

    if msg.request_id == 'image_data':
        #print(msg.result)
        print('image:', msg.result.image)
        print('mouse:', msg.result.mouse)

        left = msg.result.image.left
        top = msg.result.image.top
        
        pageX = msg.result.mouse.pageX
        pageY = msg.result.mouse.pageY
        
        print('x:', pageX-left)
        print('y:', pageY-top)

        #screenX = msg.result.mouse.screenX
        #screenY = msg.result.mouse.screenY

        #print('x:', screenX-left)
        #print('y:', screenY-top)
    
def click_image(self, msg):
    #print('click_image: self:', self)
    #print('click_image: msg:', msg)
    #print('click_image: self.name:', self.name)

    print('click_image: msg.pageX:', msg.pageX)
    print('click_image: msg.pageY:', msg.pageY)
    print('click_image: msg.screenX:', msg.screenX)
    print('click_image: msg.screenY:', msg.screenY)
    
    # f-string needs `{{ }}` to put string `{ }` in `({{image: rect}});`
    js_code = f'''
    var image = document.querySelector('[name="{self.name}"]');  // put self.name
    var rect = image.getBoundingClientRect();
    //console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
    ({{image: rect, mouse:{{ pageX:{msg.pageX}, pageY:{msg.pageY}, screenX: {msg.screenX}, screenY: {msg.screenY} }} }});  // it has to be in ( )
    '''

    #print('click_image: before run_javascript')
    #print(js_code)
    
    jp.run_task(wp.run_javascript(js_code, request_id='image_data'))
    
    #print('click_image: after run_javascript')


def main():
    global wp  # need in `wp.run_javascript`
    
    wp = jp.WebPage()
    wp.debug = True
    wp.on('result_ready', result_ready)

    txt = jp.Div(a=wp, text="Some text before Image to move it from border")
    
    img1 = jp.Img(a=wp, name='image_1', src='https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-powered-h-140x182.png', style='display: inline')
    img1.on('click', click_image)
    img1.additional_properties = ['pageX', 'pageY', 'screenX', 'screenY']

    img2 = jp.Img(a=wp, name='image_2', src='https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-powered-h-140x182.png', style='display: inline')
    img2.on('click', click_image)
    img2.additional_properties = ['pageX', 'pageY', 'screenX', 'screenY']

    return wp

jp.justpy(main)

